# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component in JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.3

I want to use JSF 2.3 with Tomcat 8. I configured this POM file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CDI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- JBoss/Weld Refrence Implementation for CDI on a Servlet Container -->
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But when I deploy the package I get this error stack:

```
27-May-2017 10:08:14.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
27-May-2017 10:08:14.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
27-May-2017 10:08:14.702 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/Web_package.war]
27-May-2017 10:08:14.742 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
27-May-2017 10:08:17.558 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
27-May-2017 10:08:17.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
27-May-2017 10:08:17.682 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.<clinit> WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (Final)
27-May-2017 10:08:18.031 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startContainer WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
27-May-2017 10:08:18.682 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.TomcatContainer.initialize WELD-ENV-001100: Tomcat 7+ detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets, Filters and Listeners.
27-May-2017 10:08:18.997 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Web_package]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessManagedBeanImpl.fire(ProcessManagedBeanImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessBean(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:227)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploySpecialized(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:109)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deploySpecialized(BeanDeployment.java:288)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:242)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiExtension.collect(CdiExtension.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
    at javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral.getTypeParameter(TypeLiteral.java:103)
    at javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral.getType(TypeLiteral.java:66)
    at com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.<clinit>(CdiUtils.java:84)
    ... 37 more

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessManagedBeanImpl.fire(ProcessManagedBeanImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessBean(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:227)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploySpecialized(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:109)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deploySpecialized(BeanDeployment.java:288)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:242)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

27-May-2017 10:08:19.009 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/Web_package.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Web_package]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

27-May-2017 10:08:19.010 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/Web_package.war] has finished in [4,307] ms
27-May-2017 10:08:19.023 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-May-2017 10:08:19.057 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-May-2017 10:08:19.058 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 4472 ms
```

With JSF 2.2 I don't have this error stack.
Do you know how I can fix this issue? Probably I need to remove or update some dependency?

Comment: There's no JSF 2.3 released nor Shiro 1.4.0 (there is a RC2).  Where did you get these JARs?  It looks like a bug within JSF itself, but its hard to tell without the real versions.

Comment: Are you sure? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/1.4.0

Comment: Hmm fair enough, missed the package name change.  The bug is on this line in the RI - https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/cdi/CdiUtils.java#L84 - specifically they're calling `getType` on an unbounded generic.

Comment: Any idea for workaround solution?

Comment: I don't believe there is one from a user's standpoint, other than turning off the extension (which there really isn't an SPI to do, you'd have to change the Extension file).